# How does this pthread_cond_wait() example work?

Tags: c, multithreading, concurrency, pthreads, posix

I got the below code from this website:

https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/#Abstract

> This simple example code demonstrates the use of several Pthread
>   condition variable routines. The main routine creates three threads.
>   Two of the threads perform work and update a "count" variable. The
>   third thread waits until the count variable reaches a specified value.

My question is- how does the below code ensure that one of the two worker threads doesn't lock on the mutex before the watcher thread locks on it? If this was to happen, the watcher thread would be locked out and `pthread_cond_wait(&count_threshold_cv, &count_mutex)` would never get called?

I am under the assumption `pthread_create()` actually begins the thread too. Is the only reason this works because the `pthread_create()` for the watcher thread begins before the `pthread_create()` for the two worker threads?! Surely this is not cast-iron and the scheduling could cause a worker thread to begin before the watcher thread? Even the compiler could potentially re-order these lines of code?

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define NUM_THREADS  3
#define TCOUNT 10
#define COUNT_LIMIT 12

int     count = 0;
int     thread_ids[3] = {0,1,2};
pthread_mutex_t count_mutex;
pthread_cond_t count_threshold_cv;

void *inc_count(void *t) 
{
  int i;
  long my_id = (long)t;

  for (i=0; i<TCOUNT; i++) {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&count_mutex);
    count++;

    /* 
    Check the value of count and signal waiting thread when condition is
    reached.  Note that this occurs while mutex is locked. 
    */
    if (count == COUNT_LIMIT) {
      pthread_cond_signal(&count_threshold_cv);
      printf("inc_count(): thread %ld, count = %d  Threshold reached.\n", 
             my_id, count);
      }
    printf("inc_count(): thread %ld, count = %d, unlocking mutex\n", 
       my_id, count);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&count_mutex);

    /* Do some "work" so threads can alternate on mutex lock */
    sleep(1);
    }
  pthread_exit(NULL);
}

void *watch_count(void *t) 
{
  long my_id = (long)t;

  printf("Starting watch_count(): thread %ld\n", my_id);

  /*
  Lock mutex and wait for signal.  Note that the pthread_cond_wait 
  routine will automatically and atomically unlock mutex while it waits. 
  Also, note that if COUNT_LIMIT is reached before this routine is run by
  the waiting thread, the loop will be skipped to prevent pthread_cond_wait
  from never returning. 
  */
  pthread_mutex_lock(&count_mutex);
  while (count<COUNT_LIMIT) {
    pthread_cond_wait(&count_threshold_cv, &count_mutex);
    printf("watch_count(): thread %ld Condition signal received.\n", my_id);
    count += 125;
    printf("watch_count(): thread %ld count now = %d.\n", my_id, count);
    }
  pthread_mutex_unlock(&count_mutex);
  pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int i, rc;
  long t1=1, t2=2, t3=3;
  pthread_t threads[3];
  pthread_attr_t attr;

  /* Initialize mutex and condition variable objects */
  pthread_mutex_init(&count_mutex, NULL);
  pthread_cond_init (&count_threshold_cv, NULL);

  /* For portability, explicitly create threads in a joinable state */
  pthread_attr_init(&attr);
  pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&attr, PTHREAD_CREATE_JOINABLE);
  pthread_create(&threads[0], &attr, watch_count, (void *)t1);
  pthread_create(&threads[1], &attr, inc_count, (void *)t2);
  pthread_create(&threads[2], &attr, inc_count, (void *)t3);

  /* Wait for all threads to complete */
  for (i=0; i<NUM_THREADS; i++) {
    pthread_join(threads[i], NULL);
  }
  printf ("Main(): Waited on %d  threads. Done.\n", NUM_THREADS);

  /* Clean up and exit */
  pthread_attr_destroy(&attr);
  pthread_mutex_destroy(&count_mutex);
  pthread_cond_destroy(&count_threshold_cv);
  pthread_exit(NULL);

}
```

Comment: From what do you get this "*... the watcher thread would be locked out and pthread_cond_wait(&count_threshold_cv, &count_mutex) would never get called?*" impression?

Comment: Both the watcher function and the worker function lock the mutex at the beginning. Either one of the worker threads proceeds, or the watching thread proceeds?

Comment: And both unlock the mutex again. The worker does it explicitly by calling `pthread_mutex_unlock()` and the watcher implicitly by calling `pthread_cond_wait()`.

Comment: Ah ok makes sense now.

Answer (score 2):

> My question is- how does the below code ensure that one of the two worker threads doesn't lock on the >mutex before the watcher thread locks on it?

The code doesn't need to ensure that. It doesn't depend on the watcher thread calling pthread_cond_wait().

The watcher thread checks `count<COUNT_LIMIT`, this is the actual condition the thread care about - or rather the inverse, when `count >= COUNT_LIMIT` - the watcher thread knows that the other threads are done.

The pthread condition variable used in `pthread_cond_wait()` is just needed in case the threads are not done, so the watcher thread can be put to sleep and woken up to check the condition it cares about.

That said, the example looks a tad silly, it's not quite clear what watcher thread wants to achieve by doing `count += 125;`

Comment: watch_count() calls pthread_mutex_lock(); before it calls pthread_cond_wait(). The worker thread also calls pthread_mutex_lock(). So if the worker thread locks-out the watcher thread, pthread_cond_wait() wont be called and there will be no "waiting"?

Comment: @user997112 Sure, that's no problem. It means the watcher thread will wait on pthread_mutex_lock() instead, and when it finally gets the mutex, it might discover that `while (count<COUNT_LIMIT)` is false, which seems to be the goal of `watch_count` - to wait until `count` has reached `COUNT_LIMIT`. Just calling `pthread_cond_wait` or getting signalled by another thread is itself never a goal with pthread condition variables. You always need a predicate to check to avoid race conditions - what you really care about is whether a flag is set, some variable got a special value etc.

Comment: Ah ok so if worker threads go first, the while loop in the watcher function will be skipped. If the watcher thread goes first, it will hold the mutex, hit the pthread_cont_wait() which then holds, releases the mutex for the worker threads and then they will release the lock and the watcher thread continues?

Comment: Yes, pretty much. If the watcher threads go first, pthread_cont_wait() unlocks the mutex and allow the worker threads to proceed. The worker threads will eventually signal the condition variable, and pthread_cont_wait() will return, with the mutex now being locked by the watcher thread again. The watcher thread will check the `while (count<COUNT_LIMIT)` again, and figure out that it's done. Anything inbetween has the same effect too, e.g. a worker thread might go 5 iteration in its loop before the watcher thread grabs the mutex.

Answer (score 0):

the comment in your code explains that you do not have to worry about that:

> Also, note that if COUNT_LIMIT is reached before this routine is run by
>     the waiting thread, the loop will be skipped to prevent pthread_cond_wait
>     from never returning.

in fact, if you notice, the while loop is run only if `COUNT_LIMIT` is not already reached by `count`. If that is the case, the `pthread_cond_signal` is not called at all.